# Trickle error :- failed:connection refused

Tags: linux, azure-iot-hub, trickle

I have an Azure Iot Hub endpoint where I have to send some data (consider small strings). I want to set the speed of sending the data to that url and am using Trickle to achieve that.

I thought

```
trickle -d 30 -u 30 wget http://armtest1.azure-devices.net
```

will do the work, but it is showing

> failed: Connection refused

Also tried like this:

```
trickle -d 30 -u 30 wget --user=[myusername] --password=[mypassword] --auth-no-challenge http://armtest1.azure-devices.net
```

But still getting the same error.

It will be very helpful if you guys kindly point out my mistake and give me a way to achieve this using trickle.

Comment: Connection refused sounds like there is no web server in port 80 at all, or there is a firewall that blocks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure IoT Hub grants access to endpoints by verifying a token against the shared access policies and identity registry security credentials. Azure IoT Hub supports MQTT, AMQP, and HTTPS, these supported protocols transports tokens in different ways.HTTPS implements authentication by including a valid token in the Authorization request header. 
If you want to access(send data) to Azure IoT Hub using REST API, an existing device need to be specified.Please try to execute the following command:

```
trickle -s -d 30 -u 30 \
wget --header="Authorization:<generated SAS token for device>" \
     --header="Content-Type:application/json" \
     --post-data '<your data in json style>' \
     "https://<your-iothub-host>.azure-devices.net/devices/<device id>/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03"
```

In the command,something need to be clarified.

- **generated SAS token for device**: you can use [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer) to generate the token.Please refer to the step 2 in this article([Sending events to IOT Hub over HTTP via REST](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chmitch/2016/11/16/sending-events-to-iot-hub-over-http-via-rest/)).
- **your data in json style**:the data you want to send to IoT Hub. It is in JSON format.
- **your-iothub-host**:You can get the hostname of IoT Hub in Azure Portal.This is the name when you created the IoT Hub.

When you executed the command successfully,there will be a response like:

```
Connecting to <your-iothub-host>.azure-devices.net (<your-iothub-host>.azure-devices.net)|<ipaddress>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 204 No Content
2018-01-03 22:33:53 (0.00 B/s) - ‘events?api-version=2016-02-03’ saved [0]
```

and, IoT Hub will receive the message, you can [monitor the events](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#monitor) through Device Explorer.

Comment: Sorry for replying you late. Thank you for the solution. Will look into it . Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome. If there is any problem, please feel free and let me know.

Comment: Thank you sir. :)

Comment: @Sumana Bagchi. If you think this reply could satisfy your requirement,please mark it as answer(https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so that it can be helpful for somebody else who encounters this similar issue.Thank you.

Comment: sure sir. Sorry for being late. Thanks for your help